# ear deploying to jboss 7 is successfully but context-root doesn't work

Tags: deployment, maven-3, jboss7.x, intellij-14

I'm using maven 3.3.3 for create ear application(with war and jars).

**web-xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/landingPage.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**ear pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>com.csaszi</groupId>
    <artifactId>topModule</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>berszamfejto-ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.csaszi</groupId>
        <artifactId>berszamfejto-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.csaszi</groupId>
        <artifactId>berszamfejto-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.csaszi</groupId>
        <artifactId>berszamfejto-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <includeLibInApplicationXml>true</includeLibInApplicationXml>
                <finalName>berszamfejto</finalName>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.csaszi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>berszamfejto-web</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>berszamfejto-web-1.0.war</bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>/berszamfejto</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.csaszi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>berszamfejto-ejb</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>berszamfejto-ejb-1.0.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.csaszi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>berszamfejto-persistence</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>berszamfejto-persistence-1.0.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.xml**(generated by maven install):

```
<display-name>berszamfejto-ear</display-name>  
<module>
<web>
  <web-uri>berszamfejto-web-1.0.war</web-uri>
  <context-root>/berszamfejto</context-root>
</web>
```

I tried the following urls but none of them worked:

```
localhost:8081/landingPage.xhtml

localhost:8081/berszamfejto/landingPage.xhtml

localhost:8081/berszamfejto-web/landingPage.xhtml

localhost:8081/berszamfejto-ear/landingPage.xhtml

localhost:8081/berszamfejto-web/

localhost:8081/berszamfejto-ear/

localhost:8081/berszamfejto-web

localhost:8081/berszamfejto-ear

localhost:8081/berszamfejto-web-1.0

localhost:8081/berszamfejto-ear-1.0
```

and following logical names...

I think I use maven wrong because without it I found the url and the war works well. I'm sure that port number `8081` is good and I can login into administration console and deploy my ear.
Here is the end of log of deploying:

> [2016-05-28 03:04:02,872] Artifact berszamfejto-ear:ear exploded:
>   Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
>   15:04:03,204 INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876:
>   Starting deployment of "berszamfejto-ear-1.0"
>   15:04:03,474 INFO [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS018559:
>   Deployed "berszamfejto-ear-1.0"
>   [2016-05-28 03:04:03,507] Artifact berszamfejto-ear:ear exploded:
>   Artifact is deployed successfully
>   [2016-05-28 03:04:03,507] Artifact berszamfejto-ear:ear exploded:
>   Deploy took 635 milliseconds

Comment: default port for jboss is 8080 . have you changed it to 8081?

Comment: yes because my oracleDB port number is 8080 too.

Comment: localhost:8081/berszamfejto/landingPage.xhtml  should work. what are you getting when you hit this URL ?

Comment: This is still not working, but I found the solution. The problem was that the war module name is the same as my <context-root> name....This generates a DuplicateException, but thanks for assisting.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer to this post and accept it as correct answer. It might help others with similar problem. Thanks.

Comment: There were two problem. First in ear.pom in configuration of maven-ear-plugin has a finalName attribute which was 'berszamfejto'. This is equal to <context-root> name which was defined in <webModule> in configuration of maven-ear-plugin. Secondly after maven clean install usually the ear:exploded folder name is generated like this: project-ear-1.0 which is wrong, because its suffix is not .ear. But this not a big problem. We should only go to File -> Project structure -> Artifacts  then click on ear:exploded and change the output directory name with .ear extension and then deploy to AS.